# How to handle adding a file to an object in a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'm trying to write an nunit unit test for a method that sends an email in C#.  In the method being tested, a list of Attachments (System.Net.Mail.Attachment) is created and then items added to it.

```
List<Attachment> emailAttachments = new List<Attachment>();
...
emailAttachments.Add(new Attachment(file));
```

In my Unit Test, I don't know how to mock emailAttachments.Add(new Attachment(file)).  Or if it is even possible.  Currently the unit test fails when it reaches this line as the 'file' doesn't exist.  Do I create a test file and save it within the project and use/reference it?  Or is there a better way to approach it?

TIA

Comment: Maybe you could call the `Attachment` constructor that accepts a `Stream` instead? Seems like it would be easier to mock out the `Stream` than a file name, which presumably gets used internally in some way that would be hard to mock out. Of course you could create a test file, but that is starting to blur the lines between a unit test and and integration test, and could introduce additional challenges. Both valid options, I think - just think carefully if you are the first to introduce a dependency on the file server.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using `System.Net.Mail` for the messages with smtp client. If so, it would go something like this

```cs
var smtp = new SmtpClient{
 // smtp configurations here (host, port, ssl) etc
};

var message = new MailMessage(){
 // message configuration here (from, body, subj) etc
};

// and this is where you should be attaching the files based on extension or whatever way you are getting all your file paths. If its just one then ignore the loop and just pass in the file path 

var filePaths =  Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\mydirectory",".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                      .Where(f => f.EndsWith(".extension"));

foreach(var file in filePaths){
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file));
}

smtp.Send(message);
smtp?.Dispose();
```